# BitConverter.GetBytes vs Convert.ToByte

Tags: c#

Can anyone shine some light of the differences between these two? I don't know which one to use and can't really find any information on the differences of the two.

Comment: They're essentially unrelated

Comment: One gets multiple bytes and the other gets one byte?  Have you looked at the documentation for these methods?

Answer (score 2):

`BitConverter.GetBytes` Converts the specified data to an array of bytes. Whereas: `Convert.ToByte` Converts a specified value to an 8-bit unsigned integer.

You want to simply convert a number or string representation into an 8-bit unsigned integer? Then `Convert.ToByte` is what you need. If you want to get an array of bytes, maybe the number you're trying to represent can't be stored in 8-bits, then `BitConverter.GetBytes` is the method for you!

Source: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobyte(v=vs.110).aspx